# Перегрузка оператора += (iadd)

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, перегрузка-функций

Что лучше возвращать из перегруженного магического метода `__iadd__`: новый объект, или тот же самый, через `self`?

Comment: Всегда возвращайте новый объект. Иначе в коде `a = b; print(a); b += 1; print(a)` будут меняться значения `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возвращать нужно **новый** объект.

Это принципиально важный момент, потому что при использовании оператора `+=` (и других) с **изменяемыми** объектами могут возникнуть нежелательные проблемы.

Покажу наглядно, что может произойти, если мы переопределим этот оператор и все-таки будем возвращать тот же самый объект (другими словами - сделаем его **изменяемым**):

```
class SomeObj:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.val += other.val
        return self

a = SomeObj(5) 
b = SomeObj(6) 
print(id(a))  # 19774544
a += b
print(id(a))  # 19774544
print(a.val)  # 11
```

Как мы видим, адрес объекта в памяти остался **тем же самым**, потому что был возвращен **исходный** объект, и на первый взгляд все работает правильно и без ошибок, но если мы вдруг захотим написать как-то так:

```
a = SomeObj(5) 
print(a.val)  # 5
b = a
a += SomeObj(1) 
print(a.val)  # 6
print(b.val)  # 6
```

То увидим, что вследствие возврата того же самого объекта - в переменной `b`, которая содержит ссылку на **исходный** объект, изменилось значение атрибута `val`, не смотря на то, что к этой переменной никто не обращался, в будущем это может быть чревато различными side-эффектами.

---

В случае же правильной реализации с созданием нового объекта:

```
class SomeObj:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return SomeObj(self.val + other.val) 

a = SomeObj(5) 
b = SomeObj(6) 
print(id(a))  # 39177904
a += b
print(id(a))  # 39176240
print(a.val)  # 11
```

Заметим, что в данном случае ссылка в переменной `a` теперь указывает на **другой**, вновь созданный объект.

Теперь убедимся, что пример с копированием ссылки отрабатывает корректно:

```
a = SomeObj(5) 
print(a.val)  # 5
b = a
a += SomeObj(1) 
print(a.val)  # 6
print(b.val)  # 5
```

Все правильно, значение в объекте переменной `b` не изменилось, потому что в результате операции был создан **новый** объект.

Comment: `В данном случае`? Автор ничего про конкретный случай не писал, поэтому мне кажетсе различия (которые были в прошлой правке) лучше оставить

Comment: @Danis спасибо, я тут правлю ещё) не могу приучить себя делать одну большую правку, а не десять маленьких

Comment: Это общая интеллектуальная ценность. У вас хороший ответ. Не вижу причин его переписывать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy хорошо, понял.

Comment: Но всё-таки иногда лучше менять. Как со списками.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, но тогда надо быть готовым к такому неожиданному поведению)