# Поведение глобальных переменных

Tags: python

Данный код не изменит глобальные значения переменных x и y:

```py
def abc(x, y):
    x = x + [4]
    y += 'nnn'
    return print(x, y)

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = 'abc'

abc(x, y)

print(x, y)
```

вывод программы:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] abcnnn
[1, 2, 3] abc
```

Но если изменить оператор в выражении `x = x + [4]` на `x += [4]`, то список изменится для глобального имени x.
Вывод будет:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] abcnnn
[1, 2, 3, 4] abc
```

Почему так происходит? То есть неизменяемая последовательность не изменилась, а изменяемый список все же изменился без использования слова `global` в области функции. Я понимаю, что такие вещи как `x.append()` поменяли бы  глобальный x, но речь вроде идет о присваивании. А точнее о виде присваивания, что такого в операторе +=, что он позволяет менять глобальный x ?

Comment: Спасибо. Я понял, что = создаст новый локальный объект. Получается что += это не просто удобная запись, а ещё есть тонкая грань =)

Comment: Я пользуюсь правилом: "Избегай глобальных переменных, всегда, любым способом". Для меня глобальные значения - это всегда статические данные и никогда переменные. Просто комментарий для тех, кто будет бороться с глобальными переменными и поиском "что же их изменяет?"

Comment: @Dmitry вопрос на самом деле не связан напрямую с глобальными переменными. Точно так же функция `abc` могла бы быть вызвана из другой функции, и точно так же модифицировалось бы значение локальной переменной вызывающей функции при `+=`.

Comment: @insolor таки да, тема смутила. И я больше как предостережение, для тех кто будет искать решение с глобальными переменными

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def abc(x):
    x += [4]
    print(f"2 x = {x} id(x) = {id(x)}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [1, 2, 3]
    print(f"1 x = {x} id(x) = {id(x)}")
    abc(x)
    print(f"3 x = {x} id(x) = {id(x)}")
```

Результат работы:

```
1 x = [1, 2, 3] id(x) = 2421664311424
2 x = [1, 2, 3, 4] id(x) = 2421664311424
3 x = [1, 2, 3, 4] id(x) = 2421664311424
```

Это один и тот же объект id = 2421664311424

Answer (score 8):

```
def abc(x, y):
    x = x + [4]
    y += 'nnn'
    return print(x, y)
```

Тут `x` - это локальная переменная, никак не связанная с глобальной переменной с тем же именем. Но список, переданный через этот параметр - связан (он же хранится в глобальной переменной).

Когда вы делаете присваивание

```
x = x + [4]
```

- вы просто записываете в локальную переменную новое значение (новый список). Значение в глобальной переменной при этом никак не изменяется.

Когда вы делаете

```
x += [4]
```

- вы не заменяете значение в переменной на новый список, а мутируете значение (добавляете элементы в исходный список). Т.к. это же значение (список) хранится и в глобальной переменной, то это изменение отображается и в ней.

И нет, `x = x + ...` не эквивалентно `x += ...`. В первом случае создается новый список, результат записывается в x, во втором случае изменяется исходный список.

Если бы оператор `+` не создавал новый список, а модифицировал левый список, то вот такой код:

```
a = [1]
b = [2]
print(a + b)
print(a + b)
print(a + b)
print(a + b)
```

при каждом `print` выдавал бы новый результат (т.к. список `a` изменился), но он выдает один и тот же результат (как и ожидаешь интуитивно).

*Хотя, конечно, ничего не мешает написать такой класс, в котором вызов `__add__` модифицирует объект, а не создает новый, но это будет очень неинтуитивно.*

Comment: Несколько дней назад помню уже подобное обсуждали )

Comment: Несколько дней назад - не помню, помню относительно недавно было что-то про разницу `+=` и отдельных `=` и `+`. Я сначала вообще подумал, что вопрос про глобальные переменные, такое точно уже было, но оказалось что тут про мутирование переданного в функцию значения, а прямого обращения к глобальной перемнной из функции нет. Т.е. что-то похожее точно было, и наверное не один раз, но точно такого же вопроса не помню.

Answer (score 4):

`+=` - это не обязательно просто короткая запись для сложения с последующим присваиванием.

Вы можете для любого своего класса задать метод `__iadd__`, благодаря чему при `+=` может быть выполнена вообще произвольная логика.

В частности для стандартного списка `+=` работает как метод list.extend.

Поэтому он не пересоздаёт переменную с тем же именем, а изменяет существующую.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Но правильно ли я понимаю, что += для изменяемых и неизменяемых объектов ведет себя по разному? В случае с изменяемыми получается мутация (или то что задано в перегрузке операции в классе, вроде так это называется). А в случае с неизменяемыми создается новый локальный объект, как если бы использовался оператор присваивания =

Comment: @Demmiat, зависит от реализации `метод __iadd__,`

Comment: @Demmiat Ну да, всё так, потому что неизменяемые объекты нельзя изменить )

Comment: Соглашусь с Grundy, необходимо проверять реализацию метода `iadd` для типов данных, к которым данный оператор применяется во избежании неожиданного результата. Примерный разбор был в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1486005/209304)